Insulating attic room with lath and plaster walls
I am new to a 1920's home in Massachusetts and the attic was built out with one small room, using lath and plaster walls. I am looking at how to insulate the walls of this room from the rest of the attic space.
Details:

The remainder of the attic will stay as unfinished storage and the there is already adequate insulation under the floorboards above the second floor ceiling, so it is just this barrier between finished and unfinished attic that is the problem. Looking for an r-value of around 40, but more would be better if reasonable.
I have relatively easy access to the exterior of the walls (facing the unfinished attic), but getting to the space requires a rather narrow staircase with a turn. i.e I cannot bring 4'x8' foam boards up there without cutting down significantly or getting smaller sheets. Also running a loose fill blower up the space would be difficult.
I am hoping to avoid building out any additional depth to the studs if possible - similar to the point above, getting framing materials to the location will be difficult (if not impossible in some areas) and it would likely result in the moving of some ductwork as well.
Given the lack of depth (< 3") and inconsistent spacing (ranges from ~12"-16", plus numerous narrower spaces at corners) of the studs, it does not seem that traditional 15" rolled fiberglass is a great option either, requiring cutting/patching for every interval.

As far as I can tell, my options would be:

Hand pack loose cellulose behind bulging netting to get proper depth. Top off as needed as it settles.
Use smaller/cutdown foam boards and layer appropriately, and deal with price and fastening.
Use rolled fiberglass, and deal with lots of cutting and patching.

I only have experience with straightforward rolled application behind drywall and so am hoping to get some input as to whether or not my assumptions are correct, or if an alternative would be recommended.
Attaching a sample picture of the area hoping to be insulated, but happy to provide additional info as needed. Thank you
Thank you admins for the feedback -  getting used to this forum!


Your question is rather broad. There are many good options, so it's not helpful for us to just list them. Opinions on "best" are off topic. Have you done some research? Which approach seems most appealing? What specific questions do you have about implementation? Welcome, and please take the [tour].

If you have the access then adding to the depth should be easy.  Most insulation can be cut to size, a couple of snips and 15 inch will fit in in 12 inch.

Thank you, @crip659 I edited my question as I failed to include that I was hoping to avoid building out additional depth at this time.

Thank you @isherwood I have researched options, but as I am sure you know, you can find an opinion supporting most any option.  Implementation would not be the problem,  but will provide additional edits to account for what options are most appealing and add specificity .

The point isherwood was making was that you're asking a broad, discussion-based question, which doesn't work well here as you'll know once you take the [tour]. If you ask about the Pros & Cons of 2 or 3 options that you think are best, we can help you with that. Otherwise, all you'll get is another list of options with opinions and it'll still be up to you to pick what you want.

A few quick points... First, you still aren't asking a specific question. Yeah, your assumptions are reasonable. Yeah, some folks will suggest other things. Then, R-40 is way above and beyond what most homes are built to these days. R-19 is standard for fiberglass batts in 2x6 walls, and very energy-conscious builders may overlay another R-10 or so in the form of foam sheathing. You might pull back a bit since cost is apparently a concern. Even the USDE only suggests up to R-23.

ok, thank you for the feedback @isherwood i was assuming i would need to use attic recommendations (with much higher r-values) as the attic is unfinished and uninsulated  - so that is the exact type of information i was looking for!
sorry i can't be more specific, i suppose i was looking for more information than i should on this forum. I will continue my research elsewhere!

A wall's a wall. Doesn't matter how high off the ground it is. :)

Based on the picture, likely the best insulated easy method would be foil-faced foamboard with foil taped joints as a first layer over the studs (leaving the less than 3" space empty) followed by as much foamboard (not foilfaced) as you care to pay for based on the insulation you want.
You could also use a plastic vapor barrier if you prefer that.
You can net loosefill insulation if looking for a lower cost option, or fur out (as much as you care to) or build an entirely separate second non-structural wall to give it more space and contain it with drywall. If you use cellulose loose fill you can skip the vapor barrier as it limits air movement and manages moisture.

I like the foamboard idea. Use screws and panel adhesive. You don't want to be pounding on those antique walls.
